# How to use variables in ModelChoiceField queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a specific list of data in my form with Django. I am using ModelChoiceField to retrieve from the model the data I need to display in the form (to let the users select from a scolldown menu).
My query is complicate because need two filters based on variables passed by **views**

I've tried to use the sessions but in **form** is not possible to import the session (based to my knowledge).

## form.py

```py
def __init__(self, pass_variables, *args, **kwargs):
   super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.fields['initiative'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=raid_User_Initiative.objects.filter(company=pass_variables[1], username=pass_variables[0]).values_list('initiative', flat=True))
```

## view.py

```py
pass_variables = ((str(request.user), companyname))
f = Issue_form(pass_variables)
```

If I don't pass the variable the process works. The problem is with the code above as the form don't provide any error but it doesn't pass the *if f.is_valid():*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself! Anyway if anyone interested the solution is using the sessions:

## form.py

Before I declare the queryset as:

```
initiative = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=raid_User_Initiative.objects.all(), to_field_name="initiative")
```

And it is very important to use the **, to_field_name="initiative"**

After I amend the queryset as:

```
def __init__(self, user, company, *args, **kwargs):
        super(raid_Issue_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['initiative'].queryset = raid_User_Initiative.objects.filter(company=company, username=user).values_list('initiative', flat=True)
```

## view.py

```
f = raid_Issue_form(request.user, request.session['company'])
```

Hope this help!